# Class of Intervals - Python

Tags: python, class, intervals

As a part of the class Interval I need to define substraction of two intervals as

[a,b]−[c,d]=[a−d,b−c].

If we have only one interval and a number (integer or float), then substraction is defined as

1 - Interval(4,5) = [-3, -4] and Interval(4,5)-1 = [3, 4].

This is my code:

```
def __sub__ (self, other):
        if isinstance (other, Interval):
            return Interval (self.left_point - other.right_point, self.right_point - other.left_point)
        elif isinstance (other, (int, float)):
            return Interval (self.left_point - other, self.right_point - other)
        else:
            raise TypeError ('Wrong type!')

    def __rsub__ (self, other):
        return Interval(other - self.left_point, other - self.right_point)
```

Code works good, but the problem is that when I have for example 1 - Interval(4,5) = [-3, -4] I want it to return [-4, -3] it's just the order that bothers me.

Can you give me a hint for that?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Define rsub as sub with the args flipped

Comment: Or define a negation operator

Comment: You may want to have your `__init__()` swap the two endpoints if they're out of order - that would catch this, and any other similar situation (as well as the user simply giving the parameters in the wrong order).

Answer (score 0):

You can always sort the endpoints:

```
def __init__(self, start, end):
    self.left, self.right = sorted([start, end])
```

If you change the `__sub__` method to remove specific checks, you can make the endpoints fully duck typed

```
def __sub__ (self, other):
    if isinstance (other, Interval):
        return Interval (self.left_point - other.right_point, self.right_point - other.left_point)
    else:
        return Interval (self.left_point - other, self.right_point - other)
```

Comment: @Haus. Please add that to the question. It's barely legible in a comment

Comment: @Haus. Please edit your question with this information. Don't try to post multiple lines of code into a comment. There is an edit link beneath the question. Ping me when you're done

Comment: @Haus. Don't forget to include a description of the exact error

Comment: I have added this to my init method and now it seems to work good
``` self.left_point, self.right_point = sorted([left_point, args[0]]) ```.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Haus. I'm not sure where the communication is failing. Please stop posting code in the comments. Use this [link to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59324431/edit) the question